# tcp stream as mediaelement source?

Tags: windows-8, mediaelement, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to use a tcp h264 stream as a MediaElement source on Windows 8 ? Or do we need to write a custom MediaElement Source. The state goes from Opening to Closed as soon as we open the Uri:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not according to this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winappswithnativecode/thread/1709d85b-97b4-425c-a5f5-3edc4d7539e6.

James Dailey indicates that when information on how to create your own decoder is available, it will be posted [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mediasdkstuff/).

Comment: WE could not get it to work with MediaElement. We had to resort to our own custom decoder sending data to UIElement.SetSource through a WritableBitmap structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some success with the Player Framework (aka Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework):

https://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Player%20Framework%20for%20Windows%208%20Metro%20Style%20Apps&referringTitle=Home

Note: I haven't tried it with Win8 yet, I'm only using its Silverlight counterpart at the moment. But that's Microsoft official 'kit' for media.